# Cakephp: multiple levels of belongsto in model

Tags: php, cakephp

In a model, is it possible to do multiple iterations of belongsTo?

Assuming 3 tables, alerts, schedules, tasks and the model is for alerts. I want to get at a field from tasks but I have to join through schedules.

```
 alerts.schedule_id -> schedules.tasks_id -> tasks.name
```

I tried this syntax:

```
var $belongsTo = array( 
         'Schedule' => array( 
             'className' => 'Schedule', 
             'foreignKey' => 'schedule_id' 
         ), 
         'Task' => array( 
             'className' => 'Task', 
             'foreignKey' => 'task_id' 
         ));
```

But that just joins both Schedules and Tasks directly to Alerts (here's the sql that was generated:

```
LEFT JOIN `schedules` AS `Schedule` ON (`Alert`.`schedule_id` = `Schedule`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `tasks` AS `Task` ON (`Alert`.`task_id` = `Task`.`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up setting this property:

```
$this->Alert->recursive = 2;
```

In the index() function of the alerts controller.

Then I didn't have to do a separate find and was able to reference the name field in the Tasks table in index.ctp like this:

```
<td><?php echo $alert['Schedule']['Task']['name']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

in alert.php

```
CLass Alert extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'Alert';
    var $belongsTo = array( 
         'Schedule' => array( 
             'className' => 'Schedule', 
             'foreignKey' => 'schedule_id' 
         )
    ); 
}
```

in schedule.php

```
 CLass Schedule extends AppModel{
        var $name = 'Schedule';
        var $belongsTo = array( 
             'Task' => array( 
                'className' => 'Task', 
                'foreignKey' => 'task_id' 
            )
        ); 
    }
```

then `find` with `recursive=>2`

Comment: or better with containable :)

Comment: I eneded up setting this property:\r\n $this->Alert->recursive = 2;